# Python: Data displayed as ‘None’ in dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am trying to pull out data from my table into a data frame, but upon doing so, I was only shown 'None' instead of the number original value/data that i have input in my table. Codes as attached below:

```
conditions = [
(ontime['DepDelay'] <= 0),
(ontime['DepDelay'] >= 0)
]
values = ['2', '1']
ontime['DelayStatus'] = np.select(conditions, values)
pd.DataFrame(ontime)
```

[image]

However, upon pulling the data from the table 'ontime', it is showing me as 'None' instead of the value '1' or '2'

```
q4 = c.execute('''
SELECT ontime.Origin AS Origin,
   ontime.Dest AS Dest,
   ontime.DayOfMonth AS DayOfMonth,
   ontime.Month AS Month,
   ontime.Year AS Year,
   ontime.ArrDelay AS ArrivalDelay,
   ontime.DepDelay AS DepDelay,
   ontime.DelayStatus AS DelayStatus
FROM ontime
WHERE ontime.Cancelled='0' AND
  ontime.ArrDelay > '0' AND
  ontime.ArrDelay != 'Na' AND
  ontime.DepDelay != 'Na'
GROUP BY Origin, Dest, DayOfMonth,Month,Year
ORDER BY Year ASC, Month ASC, DayOfMonth ASC
''').fetchall()
q4 = pd.DataFrame (q4, columns['OriginCountry','Destination','DayOfMonthArrive','MonthArrive','YearArrive','ArrivalDelay','DepDelay','DelayStatus'])
pd.DataFrame(q4)
```

Although not entirely sure I have even change the class from a string to an integer and still I am getting the value ‘None’

[image]

Comment: What is `np` in your first code snippet and `c` in the second? `None` in the returned values indicate that the database has `NULL` values in that column. I would start by using a database client such as pgadmin or dbeaver to inspect the database tables to see if they have the data you think they do.

Comment: Right.  Your first snippet shows you creating `DelayStatus` as a computed field in a DataFrame.  That won't affect the database table.  Did you intend to change the database itself?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice they're near-necessarily numpy and some database cursor (perhaps from SQLAlchemy), though they should still indicate which are in use!

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, as what ti7 have mention, and thanks! I’ll look into a database client

Comment: @Tim Robert, yes that was what I had intended to do in the first place, which is to add in a new column into the database, however I realised the above code might only work in a df but not in a db, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @WenQing Alternatively you can compute the value in he SQL statement just like you do with numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first code snippet calculates the value for a column in a dataframe named "DelayStatus". It never saves that value back to the database. So when you do a SQL query directly, you still get `None` because the underlying database column has `NULL`.

You have at least 2 options from what I see:

1. You can just use the dataframe with the computed "DelayStatus" to do further processing.
2. You can write SQL code that updates the `DelayStatus` column in each row.